# openx capabilities

Tags: openx

i know openx is a great software. however i want to setup a project. i want to create my own ad network. what i mean is serving ads not only for all my websites, but i want to have a commercial ad network where advertisers can buy ads from qualified publishers. its like to have my own buysellads.com or my own google adwords.

can openx do this or it just cater to serve my own websites?

Answer (score 1):

Openx is a great ad serving tool, with a capability of creating different advertisers and publishers accounts, so most of your work can be done by its inbuilt functionality. and remaining functionality you want can be added easily as its a open source tool.

Answer (score 0):

Openx does not have option for buying and selling ads you. yes you can serve you ads or ads from other ad networks but as it is a open source software you can modify it as per you want.